# Multiple devices connections Wifi Direct or bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I want create an aplication for connect 5-6 devices. Which is the best solution ? Wifi Direct or Bluetooth?

I need to show diferents pictures or colors in each device and them comunicate which color has each one. Anybody has example of this?

I dont know how to start..

Comment: If my answer solves this problem, don't forget to accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better make your device an access point. Wifi direct and bluetooth are used to build connection between two clients but not several.

Comment: Thanks, but If one device is the access point, how can I comunicate with the other devices? Which library?

Comment: @user3361914 If you store pictures in a stand-alone server, then you can make it a web server and this device works only as an AP. Otherwise you can make this device a web server too. This depends on your requirement. You can use common library, like content provider, to share content like pictures.

Comment: Ok I understand.. but how can I comunicate de AP with the other devices? Thank you so much!!

Comment: @user3361914 That's another really big question which is not in the topic of this one. Hope this article could help you. http://www.freewaregenius.com/five-ways-to-transfer-files-between-pc-and-android-wirelessly-including-some-that-youve-never-heard-of/     If my answer helps, don't forget to accept it. :)

Comment: @StephenLin: It's not true that WiFi Direct is made for connections between two devices only. 
WiFi Direct can be used to connect multiple devices. One of the devices is going to be the group owner (which is comparable to an AP) and multiple other devices can join his group (connect to the AP).